# Syntax Error when making CTE in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am working on the Alex the Analyst project with Covid data.  Everything has been going well until I create the CTE. I keep getting an error for a ( before the AS. What am I missing?
Thanks!

```
WITH PopvsVac (continent, location, date, population, new_vaccinations, rolling_people-vac) 
AS
(
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations,
SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) AS rolling_people_vac
, (rolling_people_vac/population)* 100
FROM `covid-project-2022.covid_data.covid_deaths` dea
JOIN `covid-project-2022.covid_data.covid_vac` vac
    ON dea.location = vac.location
    AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT null
)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Is the hyphen in rolling_people-vac acceptable without some delimiters (like quotes)?

Comment: @tinazmu that was a typo.  Thank you for catching it! After messing around with the query for a while it is now working.